# How to limit the number of threads that opencv uses in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I am designing a program which will run continuously on a ROC64. It includes the usage of BackgroudsubtractorMOG2(a background-subtracting algorithm implemented in opencv). Opencv seems to use multithreading optimization in this algorithm and it eats up all the CPU resources. I understand that in C++ we can limit the number of threads by using setNumThreads().Is there a similar thing in Python or I must find another way to work around it?

Comment: If the threads are being started by opencv layer (c++ code) python wouldn't control it. You need an opencv API for that

Comment: You can also call  `cv2.setNumThreads(1)` from the python-wrapper for opencv.

Comment: Darkonaut's  comment should be the accepted answer.  It helped me out with the same question

Answer (score 2):

You can use **cv2.setNumThreads(n)** (Where n = number of threads)

But it didn't work for me, its still using all the CPU.